# ggplot with custom legend.text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot to generate some graphics but get the following error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : could not find function "label.theme"
```

when trying to specify the label names.

This basic graph gets generated correctly:

```
p <- ggplot(as.data.frame(list(a=1:5, b=1:5,c=factor(c(1,1,2,2,2)))), aes(x=a,y=b, color=c)) + geom_path(size=1)
p
```

But this graph produces the above error.

```
p + opts(legend.text=letters[1:2])
```

Am I not setting the legend text correctly?

Comment: The `legend.text` argument in `opts` doesn't set the legend text _values_ it alters the legend text _formatting_. So you'd pass it something like `theme_text(size = 3,colour = "blue")` to change the size and colour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This accomplishes what you want I think:

```
p + scale_colour_discrete(labels=letters[1:2])
```